# resolving a promise in a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, promise

i am having trouble with how to resolve and pass data back from a chained promise. I am using node js, with request-promise. Here is my code

```
start(name)
   .then(firstFunction)
   .then(secondFuntion)
   .then(function(){
       // i want to return data from secondfunction  back  
   ))
```

the problem is in secondFunction i have a for loop that performs a call on each object i got from firstFunction, which is an array of objects. do i resolve the promise after each iteration or after all iterations. Would it be smarter to creat a global object and save the result into that and return that result? my code for secondFunction looks like this

```
var secondFunction = function(data){
    var promise = new Promise(function(){
        for(var i= 0; i <data.length; i ++){
            options = { url: "", jason: true}
            rp.(options)
              .then(function(resp){
                // i do something with respose and need to save this 
               //should i resolve the promise here??
              })
              .catch(function(err){
              });
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
```

EDIT

i figured it out! Thanks for all the help, in my second function i did this

```
var task = function(item){
     // performed the task in here
}

var actions = data.map(task);
return Promise.all(actions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal pattern for performing an async action on each item in an array, is to make the action into a function that returns a Promise, you then use `[].map()` to map the array of values, into an array of Promises. You then use `Promise.all()`, that takes an array of Promises, and returns a single Promise that resolves with an array of values, when all the Promises in the original array are resolved. It looks like this:

```
var secondFunction = function(data) {
  var promisesArray = data.map(rp);
  return Promise.all(promisesArray);
}
```

Your third `.then()` will have an array of values resolved from applying `rp` on each of the items in `data`, in the order they appeared in `data`.

A shorter version with some ES6 sugar is:

```
const secondFunction = data => Promise.all(data.map(rp));
```

If you're using Bluebird, which is the de-facto promise library for server-side JS, you can use the shorthand, `Promise.map()`, which accepts an array and a mapping function, and does the same:

```
const secondFunction = data => Promise.map(data, rp);
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! i used your suggestion